# Fichero "csv" no lee correctamente caracteres escritos desde "fputs"

Tags: php, html, apache, csv, fputcsv

Los caracteres especiales almacenados en un fichero "csv" mediante "fputs" no se visualizan correctamente.

¿Como puedo hacer para que se visualicen de la misma forma en el fichero "csv" y en la web?

Este es código PHP que utilizo:

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST))
    die ("falta parametro log en POST");
else
{
    $fecha = date('d/m/Y');
    $hora = date('G:i');
    $caracters= array("<", ">", ";", "\r\n");
    list($test1, $test2) = explode (";", $_POST["test1"]);
    $test3 = str_replace($caracters, " - ", $_POST["test3"]);   
    $test4 = str_replace($caracters, " - ", $_POST["test4"]);   
    $test5 = $_POST["test5"];

    $log_rec = $fecha.";".$hora.";".$test1.";".$test5.";".$test4.";".$test3."\n";   

    $file_log = ("fichero.csv");
    $fp = fopen($file_log , "a");
    fputs($fp , $log_rec);
    fclose($fp);
}

echo '<b>Salida pantalla test3: </b>'.$test3.'</br>';

echo mb_internal_encoding();

?>
```

Según la echo `mb_internal_encoding();` la codificación en PHP es **ISO-8859-1**.

Si escribo algún caracter especial como la "ñ" en el fichero "csv" se visualiza "Ã±".

¿Como puedo hacer para que en el "csv" los caracteres especiales se vean correctamente?

Gracias de antemano !!

Comment: Puedes probar un par de cosas, en primer lugar puedes utilizar `fputcsv` para generar el fichero, así no tienes que estar concatenando strings: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fputcsv.php Luego con `mb_internal_encoding` lo puedes usar también para poner la codificación a UTF-8. Por último, si ya estás generando el fichero en UTF-8 y el programa que lo abre no te lo reconoce, puedes añadirle el BOM al fichero. Esto son tres bytes que se añaden al principio y ayudan al programa a deducir que el fichero está en utf-8

Comment: Aquí un enlace para añadir el BOM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988581/write-utf-8-characters-to-file-with-fputcsv-in-php y aquí más info de lo que es: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes. Prueba estas cosas y si te sigue fallando pega dos imágenes, una con lo que ves en el lector de CSV y otra lo que ves cuando abres el fichero con un editor hexadecimal y vemos qué puede estar pasando.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta @ordago. No sé muy bien como enfocar/aplicar las indicaciones que me has indicado. Lo que he hecho es añadir al principio del fichero **php** la función `mb_internal_encoding(UTF8);` para que codifique en UTF8. He creado (a mano) un nuevo fichero CSV asegurándome que este codificado en UTF8 pero el problema de los caracteres especiales persiste.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto, he utilizado `utf8_decode` para cambiar la decodificación ISO-8859-1 a UTF8 de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST))
    die ("falta parametro log en POST");
else
{
    $fecha = date('d/m/Y');
    $hora = date('G:i');
    $caracters= array("<", ">", ";", "\r\n");
    list($test1, $test2) = explode (";", $_POST["test1"]);
    $test3 = str_replace($caracters, " - ", $_POST["test3"]);   
    $test4 = str_replace($caracters, " - ", $_POST["test4"]);   
    $test5 = $_POST["test5"];

    $log_rec = $fecha.";".$hora.";".$test1.";".$test5.";".$test4.";".$test3."\n";   

    $cambia_utf8 = utf8_decode ($log_rec);

    $file_log = ("fichero.csv");
    $fp = fopen($file_log , "a");
    fputs($fp , $cambia_utf8);
    fclose($fp);
}

echo '<b>Salida pantalla test3: </b>'.$test3.'</br>';

?>
```

Otra cosa que he hecho es cambiar, a través de la la apliación Excel, la decodificación del fichero "csv" a UTF8.

Gracias nuevamente a @ordago por su tiempo.

Comment: Te iba a responder ayer, pero es que tuve un día complicado, me alegro que hayas dado con la solución.